# indexing a list where there is no match in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two separate lists (of lists) that can potentially have overlapping values. Each list has a date. I would like to modify `mylist1` so that the date (`item[3]`) is the minimum of the date from `mylist1` and the corressponding date in `mylist2`. The problem I am running into is that when there is no match, I get an error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. In these cases, I would just like to not take the minimum, but instead just use the date in `mylist1`. Is there some sort of if error clause that I can put around it?

My Code:

```
mylist1 = [[u'AAA', None, u'111', u'1/1/2015'],
           [u'BBB', None, u'222', u'1/1/2012'],
           [u'CCC', None, u'333', u'1/1/2012']]

mylist2 = [(u'111', u'1/1/2011'),
           (u'333', u'2013-11-10'),
           (u'444', u'1/1/2017')]

for key, item in enumerate(mylist1):
     mylist1[key] = [item[0], item[1], item[2],
                     min(item[3], [x for x in mylist2 if x[0] == item[2]][0][1])]
```

Desired output:

```
[[u'AAA', None, u'111', u'1/1/2011'],
 [u'BBB', None, u'222', u'1/1/2012'],
 [u'CCC', None, u'333', u'1/1/2012']]
```

Comment: Just define your own special version of `min` that takes this possibility into account.

Comment: @ScottHunter seems overly involved. It'd be more clear just to wrap it in a `try` block.

Comment: @AdamSmith: How involved is "if present use min else don't"?

Comment: @ScottHunter What you described is not anything I'd call "defin[ing] your own special version of `min`" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this right, your `mylist2` is kinda used as a dictionary. Why not just make it one:

```
mylist1 = [[u'AAA', None, u'111' ,u'1/1/2015'], [u'BBB', None, u'222' ,u'1/1/2012'], [u'CCC', None, u'333' ,u'1/1/2012']]
mylist2 = [(u'111', u'1/1/2011'), (u'333', u'2013-11-10'), (u'444', u'1/1/2017')]
# assuming, you are not responsible for the form of mylist2,
# we will change it into a dictionary here:
mydict = dict(mylist2)   # easy :)
for elem_list in mylist1:
    elem_list[3] = min(elem_list[3], mydict.get(elem_list[2], elem_list[3]))
```

`elem_list` is a reference to the list, so we don't need the index of it in `mylist1` as a change in it will persist. This makes the rest of the last line easier, as we do not have to re-build the original list. The `mydict.get` prevents the error, if the desired element is not available.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist1 = [[u'AAA', None, u'111' ,u'1/1/2015'], [u'BBB', None, u'222' ,u'1/1/2012'], [u'CCC', None, u'333' ,u'1/1/2012']]
mylist2 = [(u'111', u'1/1/2011'), (u'333', u'2013-11-10'), (u'444', u'1/1/2017')]
for key, item in enumerate(mylist1):
    try:
         mylist1[key] = [item[0],item[1],item[2],min(item[3],[x for x in mylist2 if x[0] == item[2]][0][1])]
    except IndexError:
        #Put your codes that what you want to do if you got this error
        #print ("An error happened but I dont care") <--- like this for example
        pass #or just simply pass this error
```

Actually you can decide what will happen if you got IndexError, try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cool way to do it **if you have unique keys**:

```
# produce dictionaries whose keys are the matching values (have to be uniue)
mylist1dict={x[2]: x for x in mylist1}
mylist2dict={x[0]: x for x in mylist2}
# replace where needed, only use common keys
for k in set(mylist2dict) & set(mylist1dict):
    mylist1dict[k][2] = mylist2dict[k]
# this is the result
mylist1dict.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

As in some case your `min` function return an empty list You can use an `if` statement for check the it then indexing :

```
>>> for key, item in enumerate(mylist1):
...     m=min(item[3],[x for x in mylist2 if x[0] == item[2]])
...     if m :
...          mylist1[key] = [item[0],item[1],item[2],m[0][1]]
... 
>>> mylist1
[[u'AAA', None, u'111', u'1/1/2011'], 
 [u'BBB', None, u'222', u'1/1/2012'], 
 [u'CCC', None, u'333', u'1/1/2012']]
```